# Generate pre-filled fillable pdf

Tags: sqlite, pdf, autofill

I have an html page that should return a fillable pdf that needs to be generated/interface with prexisting forms for each user that auto-fills a large portion of the form.

How would I serve them this pdf?

Ideally each of these filled fields should be editable when they download the forms since differing amounts of information are available from the user profile for pre-filling but getting a general case going at the moment would be great. A django/Python friendly method is preferred.

EDIT: To be clear, a fillable pdf exists that needs to be populated prior to download.

Comment: There is a python package that generates  pdfs. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pdf

Comment: These PDFs are prexisting fillable (government) documents, so I'm trying to interface with that.

Comment: Concerning government forms you should be cautious - since governments often still use xfa forms. If the pdfs in question contain xfa forms (in contrast to regular acroform forms), you may need special software to fill then i.